# Two definitions of embedded tropicalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

Melody Chan gave two definitions of embedded tropicalization in her Lectures on Tropical Curves and Their Moduli Spaces. Let $K$ be a nonarchimedean valued field and $X$ be a subvariety of $(\mathbb{G}_m)^n$, which in other words means $X$ is defined by the ideal of the Laurent polynomial ring $K[x_1^{\pm},\cdots,x_n^{\pm}]$. One definition is that the tropicalization $Trop(X)$ of $X$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\{(v(x_1),\cdots,v(x_n))|(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in X(L)\, for\, L/K\, a\,valued\,extension\},$$
where a valued extension $L/K$ means $L$ is a valued field over $K$ whose valuation restricts to $v$ on $K$.

Another definition is that $Trop(X)$ is the image of the map $X^{an}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that sends $p:Spec(L)\to X$ to $(\nu_{x_1}(p),\cdots,\nu_{x_n}(p))$, where $X^{an}$ consists of all the maps $p:Spec(L)\to X$ and $\nu_{x_i}(p)=v(p^\sharp(x_i))$. My question is how to understand $X(L)$. Usually it means the fibre product, but why are these two definitions compatible? Generally we don't have $K[x_1^{\pm},\cdots,x_n^{\pm}]/I\otimes_KL\to L$.

Comment: $X = V(I)$ for some prime ideal $I \subset K[X], X= (x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1})$, choose an algebraic closure, extend the valuation, for $K \subset L \subset \overline{K}$ let $X(L) = \{ x \in (L^*)^n, \forall f \in I, f(x) = 0\}$, it corresponds to the $L$-homomorphisms $L[X]/I \to L$ and $X(\overline{K})$ corresponds to the $L$-homomorphisms $L[X]/I \to \overline{K}$ thus the $Gal(\overline{K}/L)$ orbits correspond to its maximal ideals